# Find the most frequent numbers in an array using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<int> a = new List<int>{ 1,1,2,2,3,4,5 };
```

What's the quickest way to do this with LINQ?

I'm new to LINQ

Comment: I provided you a solution that outputs this result.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The key here is using [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) and the aggregation method [`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx):

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1,1,2,2,3,4,5 };

// group by value and count frequency
var query = from i in list
            group i by i into g
            select new {g.Key, Count = g.Count()};

// compute the maximum frequency
int whatsTheFrequencyKenneth = query.Max(g => g.Count);

// find the values with that frequency
IEnumerable<int> modes = query
                              .Where(g => g.Count == whatsTheFrequencyKenneth)
                              .Select(g => g.Key);

// dump to console
foreach(var mode in modes) {
    Console.WriteLine(mode);
}
```

Comment: +1 for THE variable name

Comment: Thanks, just helped me out of the same problem

Comment: Note that this can explode when input list is empty. That may or may not be desired. Furthermore, aren't you iterating the `query` twice? one for `Max` and one for final select?

Answer (score 2):

Jason's answer is correct, but you can perform this operation in one LINQ operation.

```
        List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        // return most frequently occurring items
        var query = from i in list
                    group i by i into g

                    let maxFreq = (from i2 in list 
                                  group i2 by i2 into g2
                                  orderby g2.Count() descending 
                                  select g2.Count()).First() 

                    let gCount = g.Count()

                    where gCount == maxFreq 

                    select  g.Key;

        // dump to console
        foreach (var mode in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(mode);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Tres MostCommon<Tsrc, Tres>(this IEnumerable<Tsrc> source, Func<Tsrc, Tres> transform)
{
    return source.GroupBy(s => transform(s)).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).First().Key;
}
```

And in your example with integral types you can call it as:

```
List<int> a = new List<int>{ 1,1,2,2,3,4,5 };
int mostCommon = a.MostCommon(x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from num in a
group num by num into numg
let c = numg.Count()
order by c descending
select new { Number = numg.Key, Count = c }
```

Comment: This only orders by frequency and computes frequency. It does not, however, find the item(s) that occured the most.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most frequent number can also be achieved in a single query like this-

```
  var query = (from i in list
               group i by i into g
               orderby g.Count() descending
               select new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).FirstOrDefault();
  if (query == null) Console.WriteLine("query = NULL");
  else  Console.WriteLine("The number '{0}' occurs {1} times.", query.Key, query.Count);
```

Null check is not really required but it may be useful when null is actually expected (like Empty list?)

Comment: This method does not catch lists that have multiple items with the highest frequency.