# How to build a histogram for a list of int in C#

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the most frequent numbers in an array using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169299/find-the-most-frequent-numbers-in-an-array-using-linq)

I have a list of int, `List<int> demoList`, which is something like `{1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1}` and I want to write a LINQ statement for obtaining the number with the highest number of appearences from that list, which in my case is `1`.

Comment: It's dup, but this question is a lot clear and better formated ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 int highestAppearanceNum = demoList.GroupBy(i => i)
            .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
            .Select(grp => grp.First())
            .First();
```

**Edit**: If you also want to know which number appears how often:

```
var appearances = demoList.GroupBy(i => i)
    .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
    .Select(grp => new { Num = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() });
if (appearances.Any())
{
    int highestAppearanceNum = appearances.First().Num;     // 1
    int highestAppearanceCount = appearances.First().Count; // 5
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var list = new[] { 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1 };
var result = list
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(x => new { Number = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
    .FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine("highest number = {0}, count = {1}", result.Number, result.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` clause.

```
var groups = 
    from i in demoList
    group i by i into g
    select new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
```

From here you can say

```
var max = groups.Max(g => g.Count);
groups.Where(g => g.Count == max).Select (g => g.Value); // { 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query =
    from i in demoList
    group i by i into g
    orderby g.Count() descending
    select new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };

var result = query.First();
Console.WriteLine(
    "The number with the most occurrences is {0}, which appears {1} times",
    result.Value,
    result.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

I appologise in advance:

```
        List<int> demoList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1 };

        Dictionary<int,int> keyOrdered = demoList.GroupBy(i => i)
            .Select(i => new { i.Key, Count = i.Count() })
            .OrderBy(i=>i.Key)
            .ToDictionary(i=>i.Key, i=>i.Count);

        var max = keyOrdered.OrderByDescending(i=>i.Value).FirstOrDefault();

        List<string> histogram = new List<string>();

        for (int i = max.Value; i >-1 ; i--)
        {
            histogram.Add(string.Concat(keyOrdered.Select(t => t.Value>i?"| ":"  ")));
        }

        histogram.Add(string.Concat(keyOrdered.Keys.OrderBy(i => i).Select(i => i.ToString() + " ")));

        histogram.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine("Max: {0}, Count:{1}", max.Key, max.Value);
```

when i read the title i thought of this and it made me smile.. (prolly full of bugs too!)